# php replace values of array elements based on the lookup from another array

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I have an array `$fruits` which is as following:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'fruit' => string 'banana' (length=5)
      'origin' => string 'cat1' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'fruit' => string 'orange' (length=6)
      'origin' => string 'cat2' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'fruit' => string 'apple' (length=5)
      'origin' => string 'cat3' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'fruit' => string 'lemon' (length=5)
      'origin' => string 'cat4' (length=4)
```

and I have another array `$origins` which has the old origins and new origins of the fruits:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'oldOrigin' => string 'cat1' (length=5)
      'newOrigin' => string 'new1' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'oldOrigin' => string 'cat2' (length=5)
      'newOrigin' => string 'new2' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'oldOrigin' => string 'cat3' (length=5)
      'newOrigin' => string 'new3' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'oldOrigin' => string 'cat4' (length=5)
      'newOrigin' => string 'new4' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'oldOrigin' => string 'cat5' (length=5)
      'newOrigin' => string 'new5' (length=4)
```

The question is how to replace the `origin` values in the first array with the `newOrigin` values, by looking up on the value of `oldOrigin`.

so the result will be:

`$fruits` :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'fruit' => string 'banana' (length=5)
      'origin' => string 'new1' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'fruit' => string 'orange' (length=6)
      'origin' => string 'new2' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'fruit' => string 'apple' (length=5)
      'origin' => string 'new3' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'fruit' => string 'lemon' (length=5)
      'origin' => string 'new4' (length=4)
```

thanks in advance for the help, i am using php 5.

Comment: And what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hello, Please show us what did you try to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
 foreach($fruits as $fruit)
{
    foreach($origins as $origin)
        {
            if($origin['oldOrigin'] == $fruit['origin'])
                {
                    $fruit['origin'] == $origin['newOrigin'];
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: i get this error `Warning: Illegal string offset 'oldOrigin`, can you help please?

Comment: Can you show me your entire code + your complete values print_r() of your both arrays ?